# Lost sound in PP 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I lost sound to FB & Youtube videos today just before installing recent updates, which did not restore or fix the problem. I reinstalled flash as worked in the past, not this time. Also received a prompt on FB to install PulseAudio which I did, ineffective. I read the suggestions at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure ...but unable to tell which if any applied to PP 12.04. I do have a dual/boot system with Windows XP but haven't accessed that side in 2 years and was unable last time I tried. I see my version is reaching end-of-life, is there an upgrade? I have not received from the usual trusted source who sends updates.

Comment: I just found this, don't know entirely what to make of it. I said mine was Ubuntu but fact is that quit working when Unity went away and have been using Kubuntu since, no other versions seem to work. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/firefox-52-no-sound-pulseaudio-alsa-linux

Comment: Yesterday after listening to a voice-message, a Youtube video played perfectly for some reason. Browser later collapsed, reopened, no sound again. Correction to above, am using Lubuntu (debian), not Ku

Comment: Please help? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found and installed 14.04 LTS, sound has been restored in other (default) Ubuntu version (not Lubuntu)

Comment: Sound not working in LXDE or Lubuntu versions of 14.04. I noticed that In Ubuntu (default) that RythmnBox & Audacious were enabled, while in others, PulseAudio. Nothing plays for me with PulseAudio, otherwise I prefer LXDE & Lubuntu lighter versions; can someone please tell me how to get sound to play in them? Ubuntu (default) is much slower.

Comment: Went into RythmBox and Audacious settings, enabled those apps with ALSA, disabled PulseAudio, sound on Youtube works fine now.